# Solving summation of fractional powers with floor

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, even-and-odd-functions

$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor} = 2 * (2^{k/2}-1)$ when k is even

$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor} = 3 * 2^{(k-1)/2}-2$ when k is odd

How can I solve this by induction or derive the RHS from LHS?
One possible approach was to consider even, and odd cases as 2m and (m-1)/2 without the floor, but the RHS I got was different.

A good research paper I found on resizable arrays for context: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2801681_Resizable_Arrays_in_Optimal_Time_and_Space

Comment: Try writing out the terms of the sum for some medium size numbers, like $k=7$ and $k=8$, and see if that gives you any ideas. The research paper doesn’t sound at all relevant, and the sums should be simple to write out for small values of $k$.

Comment: @SteveKass, I did try changing the limits from 1 for odd and from 2 for even. While the equality definitely holds, the sum of finite numbers considering it be a geometric progression didn't work well as I expected it to. The research paper was for context on how I got the equation - Buddy Implementation of locate for dynamic arrays.

Comment: I meant write out the sums in some specific small cases. For example, if $k=4$, $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor} = 2^{\lfloor0/2\rfloor}+2^{\lfloor1/2\rfloor}+2^{\lfloor2/2\rfloor}+2^{\lfloor3/2\rfloor}=2^0+2^0+2^1+2^1$. Do you see a useful pattern developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said,
in these kind of problems,
it pays to consider
even and odd values separately.

Let
$f(k)
=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor}
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(2k)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{2k-1} 2^{\lfloor{i/2}\rfloor}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (2^{\lfloor{2i/2}\rfloor}+2^{\lfloor{(2i+1)/2}\rfloor})\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (2^{i}+2^{i})\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{i}\\
&=2(2^k-1)\\
\end{array}
$

and
$f(2k+1)
=f(2k)+2^k
=2(2^k-1)+2^k
=3(2^k)-2
$.

Since
$k
=\dfrac{2k}{2}
=\lfloor\dfrac{2k+1}{2}\rfloor
$,
you get the specified formulas.

Comment: I was beating around the bush after coming down to $2(2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 +...)$
Thank you for the detailed answer!
Edit: My up-vote, unfortunately, does not show up because of the reputation.

Comment: You now have a few points.